# Don't know how to handle large database

Tags: iphone, database, core-data, ios5

I am new to programming in IOS, using Xcode 4 for IOS 5. I have programming experience for android devices and am now trying to learn iPhone dev environs.. heres my problem, Ive searched without any success what this could be caused by...

I am trying to create a simple navigation view type app, for example, opening screen to display a list of items from an sqlite database, then select an item to view details..

I have so far created this effect successfully with about 30 rows in my sqlite database, but as soon as I add a large amount of rows (i.e. 700 - 1000) the app crashes and I start to get the table Z_METADATA does not exist...

So I investigated and what I found is that when I am using the small amount of test data, 30 rows, the sqlite database file is successfully copied and the Z tables are added correctly, BUT when I add more rows (even just duplicating ones that I know aren't causing problems) the Z tables do not get created, and each time i have destroyed the app (on the simulator) before re-running it to ensure a clean install...

any ideas? Im pulling my hair out.

**Update, even with 5 rows, but a lot of data in a blob type in the DB, still same crash errors.

Thanks,

-LKabo

P.S. I know its a mess, lol, but Im still in the pre-pre preocess of learning as I go before I get it all cleaned up for production.. If u need to see more sections, let me know..

CODE:
(FROM APP DELEGATE)

```
//  NJLawAppDelegate.m
//  Title 2C
//
//  Created by macbook air on 1/26/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Kaboserv.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NJLawAppDelegate.h"
#import "Statutes.h"
#import "NJLawMasterViewController.h"

@implementation NJLawAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize titles;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    

databaseName = @"Title_2C.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

[self setDatabase];
[self readStatutes];
 
 
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NJLawMasterViewController *controller = (NJLawMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 stub
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 stub
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 stub
 */
}   

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/* stub */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
[self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 
}
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Title_2C" withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return __managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Title_2C.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
} 



-(void) setDatabase{

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Title_2C.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
        return;
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Title_2C.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

-(void) getStatutes {
// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;

// Init the animals Array
 titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//      sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database);


//  NSLog(@"Answer = %@", sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database));
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"open OK, %@", databasePath);
    
    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from title2c";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    
    NSLog(@"statement saved ok..");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"got past if statement to test database connection..");
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aStatute = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            NSString *aPriority = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
            
          //  NSLog(@"Title = %@ and Desc = %@ and both = %@", aTitle, aDescription);
            
            
            Statutes *statute = [[Statutes alloc] initWithStatute:aStatute title:aTitle description:aDescription priority:aPriority];
            
        //  NSLog(@"statute = %@", statute);
                            
            [titles addObject:statute];
            
            //[statute release];
            NSLog(@"inside of select while loop...stat=%@, title=%@", aStatute, aTitle);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR WITH SQL STATEMENT..");

    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    
}
sqlite3_close(database);
     
NSLog(@"got to end of select statement");
}
```

and here is my log file containing the error, keep in mind that if i use a couple of "short" records i don't have the problem, but when I use a couple of records with a lot of data in the blob field I still get the error..

```
2012-01-27 16:28:18.661 Title 2C[4576:fb03] open OK, /Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0B260DE-838E-49F3-802C-C60D0E22B595/Documents/Title_2C.sqlite
2012-01-27 16:28:18.662 Title 2C[4576:fb03] statement saved ok..
2012-01-27 16:28:18.664 Title 2C[4576:fb03] got past if statement to test database connection..
2012-01-27 16:28:18.665 Title 2C[4576:fb03] inside of select while loop...stat=2C:1-1., title=Short title;  rules of construction

 {OMITTED MORE LIKE THIS, shows all records in database here OK...}

2012-01-27 16:28:19.455 Title 2C[4576:fb03] got to end of select statement
2012-01-27 16:28:19.474 Title 2C[4576:fb03] CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0B260DE-838E-49F3-802C-C60D0E22B595/Documents/Title_2C.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'
2012-01-27 16:28:19.478 Title 2C[4576:fb03] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain  Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x8155290  {NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at /Users/macbook/Library/Application  Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0B260DE-838E-49F3-802C- C60D0E22B595/Documents/Title_2C.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA',  NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1}, {
 NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 1;
 NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /Users/macbook/Library/Application  Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C0B260DE-838E-49F3-802C- C60D0E22B595/Documents/Title_2C.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA'";
 }
(gdb)
```

Comment: Sorry, but no one is going to be able to answer this as written. iOS can handle large databases fine; there are lots of examples of this. (And 700-1000 rows qualifies as a small database.) There must be other problems with your app that only you will be able to narrow down.

Comment: please post code i disagree with @smparkes saying that "only you will be able to narrow down" but we do need to see the code

Comment: agreed that it is small, i mean to say largER than 30 records, ill post some of my problem areas..

Answer (score 3):

Your code is a mess. You have both some Core Data code in there and you use the raw SQLite API. Make up your mind which one to use and then remove all code that is not relevant.